# Wrong number of data frames when identifying all possible combinations for a certain variable

Tags: r, combinations

I have the following data frame

```
Name <- c("Jhon", "Lee", "Suzan", "Abhinav",
          "Brain", "Ron","Cat","Mike","Bob","Sue","Carl")
Vote <- rep(letters[1:21],each=10, len=230)
z <- as.data.frame (cbind(Name, Vote))
```

I want to create a list of data frames which represent all possible combinations of 6 names with their respective votes (out of 11 that I have) and which include as well the 5 other names appended.
The following gives me all possible combinations of 6 names, which is 462

```
comb<-combn(unique(as.character(z$Name)), 6)
```

comb has 462 columns, so it is the correct output.

The following code creates the list of all data frames across the combinations.

```
combdf <- apply(comb, 2, function(vec) z[ z$Name %in% vec, ] )
```

The following code should create the output that I want

```
output <- z %>%
  pull(Name) %>%
  unique %>%
  combn(., 3, FUN = function(vec) 
    z %>%
      filter(Name %in% vec) %>%
      bind_rows(z %>% 
                  filter(!Name %in% vec) %>% 
                  rename(Name2 = Name, Vote2 = Vote)) %>%
      mutate(across(c(Name2, Vote2),
                    ~ .[order(is.na(.))])), simplify = FALSE)
```

My problem is that `output` has 165 data frames and I expect 462. In addition, each data frame in `combdf` , if I am not wrong, should have 230 rows (as does my original data frame - z). However, this is not the case. For ex., number one has 226, number four has 229, number 18 has 228 (checked at random).

Comment: Each data frame in `combdf` has 126 rows.

Comment: @akrun you mean when I combine the vectors to create z data frame? Yes, i have a warning message as the two vectors are not equal. This is created data. My original data frame has the same number of rows and when I run the code above I get the same results (i.e 165 data frames and rows in combdf being different from 230). I do not have any errors/warning messages with my original data frame.

Comment: ok, I was using `data.frame(Name, Vote)`

Comment: @LC-datascientist, when I run the code I get the number of rows as described in the question.

Comment: @akrun, if I understand correctly your question, no. I am trying to achieve what is described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67389023/using-combn-to-create-list-of-dataframes-for-all-combinations-of-variables-sel. In this response the output is ok. it has 10 data frames as expected. Here i expect 462 and only have 165. The differing (from 230) number of rows in combdf is just another puzzle that I thought might be related to the output I get.

Comment: Strange. I'm getting unevenly between 125 and 126 rows for the data frames when I run your code. I restarted my R session too.

Comment: As the other comment described, you have rows around 126, 125 i..e `sapply(combdf, nrow)`  May be you were looking at the rownames which can be deceptive

Comment: @arkun you're right I was confused by row names. What about the number of dataframes in output. Am I right to say they are only  165? Should I  expect 462? I understand this might be a math question, but I hope you have an idea. thanks

Comment: The `462` is based on combinations  of 6, while `combn(unique(z$Name), 3)` this is for 3 and it is 165

Comment: yes, I missed to change 3 to 6 in the function. Stupid mistake. If you want you can post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `m` in `combn` determines the number of combinations as well

```
>combn(1:6, 2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    2     3     3     3     4     4     5
[2,]    2    3    4    5    6    3    4    5    6     4     5     6     5     6     6
> combn(1:6, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     2     2     2     2     2     2     3     3     3     4
[2,]    2    2    2    2    3    3    3    4    4     5     3     3     3     4     4     5     4     4     5     5
[3,]    3    4    5    6    4    5    6    5    6     6     4     5     6     5     6     6     5     6     6     6
```

Note the number of column difference.  Similarly, in the OP's post, the 'combdf' was created with `m = 6`, while in the tidyverse code, the `m` used is 3.  Thus is makes a difference from `462` to `165`